# Deferring Delivery of Emails with Exchange

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, mapi

Is there a way to defer the delivery of emails sent to a Microsoft Exchange server? I would like to be able to send an email using a corporate Exchange server as the SMTP server, and specify the delivery time of the email in a header or otherwise.

A search of the MAPI documentation turned up [the PidTagDeferredDeliveryTime MAPI attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815337(v=office.15).aspx), but I would need to be able to set that attribute for each particular email that I send to the server. Can it be specified in an SMTP header? If not, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Deferred delivery won't work if your sending a Message via SMTP, If you use an Exchange API like MAPI or EWS eg https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220496%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx because these use the Exchange Store to submit messages it will read that MAPI property you referred to and delay sending of the messages.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that using straight SMTP.